# GWT application in local tomcat: nocache.js 404 not found

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, gwt, gwtp

Currently I'm trying to build (maven) and run (tomcat 6.0.36) a GWT application. The application is working great in eclipse, the build was successful. There are no issues during the tomcat startup.

When I call the landing page, i get a http 404 error, because the nochache.js file isn't there. It is correct there is no nochache.js file in the exploded war directory. But why? Any idea?

Firebug:
[image: firebug screenshot]

Html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="dashboard/dashboard.nocache.js"></script>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Dashboard</groupId>
    <artifactId>Dashboard</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
        <gwtVersion>2.5.0</gwtVersion>
        <gwtp.version>0.7</gwtp.version>
        <agoVersion>2.7.4</agoVersion>
        <oracleJdbcVersion>11</oracleJdbcVersion>

        <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.5 -->
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>smartgwt</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            ...
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ========================================== -->
        <!-- ================== Logger ================ -->
        <!-- ========================================== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.allen-sauer.gwt.log</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-log</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ========================================== -->
        <!-- ================== GWT ================ -->
        <!-- ========================================== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
            <artifactId>requestfactory-server</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
            <artifactId>requestfactory-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MVP component -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwtp-mvp-client</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dispatch component -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwtp-dispatch-client</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwtp-dispatch-server-guice</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Crawler component -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwtp-crawler</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Annotation component -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwtp-processors</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>gin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Some more third-party dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-multibindings</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.gflot</groupId>
            <artifactId>gflot</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>oracle</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gwtext</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwtext</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${gwtVersion}</version>

                    <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see gwt-maven-plugin 
                        documentation at codehaus.org -->
                    <configuration>
                        <runTarget>Dashboard.html</runTarget>
                        <module>com.xxx.dashboards.Dashboard</module>
                        <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>

                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                    <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>8.1.10.v20130312</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        ...
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Do I need any adaptions in my pom.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with following lifecycle-mapping.

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId> org.apache.maven.plugins </groupId>
                                <artifactId> maven-dependency-plugin
                                </artifactId>
                                <versionRange> [2.1,) </versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>unpack</goal>
                                    <goal>build-classpath</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <ignore></ignore>
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>
                                    org.codehaus.mojo
                                </groupId>
                                <artifactId> gwt-maven-plugin </artifactId>
                                <versionRange> [2.5.0,) </versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <ignore></ignore>
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                                <artifactId> maven-processor-plugin </artifactId>
                                <versionRange> [2.0.5,)
                                </versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>process</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <ignore></ignore>
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId> org.codehaus.mojo </groupId>
                                <artifactId>
                                    build-helper-maven-plugin
                                </artifactId>
                                <versionRange> [1.7,) </versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>add-source</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <ignore></ignore>
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-archiver</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you configured executions for the gwt-maven-plugin is wrong: it should be `<executions>` and `<execution>` rather than, respectively, `<pluginExecutions>` and `<pluginExecution>`, and they should go outside the `<configuration>`.
And you must reference the gwt-maven-plugin from the `<build>`/`<plugins>`, not just `<pluginManagement>` (it works for the maven-compiler-plugin because it's implicitly bound to the compile phase by the `<packaging>war</packaging>`; and it's OK for the jetty-maven-plugin because it'll be called from the command-line)

---

As a side note: put all your GWT dependencies (except gwt-servlet, but particularly gwt-user) with `<scope>provided</scope>` to avoid bundling them into your WAR. Also, requestfactory-apt is meant to be used at compile-time, and is useless at runtime, so use `<scope>provided</scope>` too; and requestfactory-server is a subset of gwt-servlet so you don't need both.
I strongly suggest you split your project in several modules though, with one module for the GWT client-side code, and one module for the server-side code (and possible a third one for the code you share between the client and server, e.g. GWT-RPC or RequestFactory interfaces, and the classes you'd transport over GWT-RPC).